# The parent theme is missing. Please install the "ABC" parent theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress-3.3.1 instance and two themes installed. Theme A is parent theme and theme B is a child.

I'm trying to make theme C which is a child of B, but I get a message in wordpress:

> The parent theme is missing. Please install the "B" parent theme.

Is it possible to make double inheritance in Wordpress themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a file named `index.php` to **Theme B** seems to trigger **Theme C** to show up as 'working' (so you can activate it).

I guess you could then `require_once` the `index.php` file from **Theme A** in your new `index.php` in **Theme C**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Parent theme folder was north-wp but in the child theme CSS I saw
`Version: 1.0.0
    Author: fuelthemes
    Author URI: http://themeforest.net/user/fuelthemes
    Template: north
    Text Domain: north`

What was missing is the additional **-wp** in Template: as WordPress looks at the theme directory name as a reference.